# Which keyboard shortcut functions are already implemented in oxyplot?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, oxyplot

I'm looking for a list of all shortcuts functions which oxyplot already implemented!

Like A == reset
Ctrl + Left Mouse button ...etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this documentation is what you are looking for, but it's currently marked with "TODO", so probably not complete: [docs oxyplot](https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controllers/index.html#default-input-bindings).

So I did some digging in the [`PlotController.cs`](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/PlotController/PlotController.cs):

- Pan*:
   
  Right mouse button,
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left mouse button,
  <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> key, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> key for fine pan
- Pan-Zoom:
   Touch (don't know the details on that)
- Zoom*:
  Mouse wheel,
   
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Mouse wheel for fine zoom
- Zoom in*:
   
  Mouse extra button 1,
  'Add', 'PageUp', <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+'Add'/'PageUp' for fine
- Zoom out*:
   
  Mouse extra button 2,
  'Subtract', 'PageDown', <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+'Subtract'/'PageDown' for fine
- Zoom by rectangle:
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Right mouse button,
  Middle mouse button,
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left mouse button
- Reset*:
   
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Right mouse button double-click,
  Middle mouse button double-click,
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left mouse button double-click
- Reset axes:
  <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>,
  Shake-Gesture (I guess on a mobile device)
- Copy bitmap:
    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Copy code:
      <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Al</kbd>t+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Copy properties:
    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Tracker:
   Left mouse button,
  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Left mouse button for points only tracker,
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Left mouse button for free tracker (show mouse coordinates basically),
  Touch-Down (while touching I guess)

*You can zoom/pan/reset a single axis by positioning the mouse cursor
over the axis before starting the zoom/pan.

I guess I could learn some formatting skills for StackExchange to get this list a bit nicer. And after doing this research I should maybe go and try to update that documentation page.

That's all there is in the PlotController at the moment, though maybe my list is a bit simplified as there is should be a difference with "ZoomInAt" and just "ZoomIn", which is probably referring to the position of the mouse cursor.